# Can you cast Call Lightning while submerged underwater?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic, druid

We are running an underwater campaign where everyone is an aquatic race, and most of the campaign will take place completely underwater. Call Lightning says:

"A storm cloud appears in the shape of a cylinder that is 10 feet tall with a 60-foot radius, centered on a point you can see within range directly above you. The spell fails if you can't see a point in the air where the storm cloud could appear (for example, if you are in a room that can't accommodate the cloud)."

Does this literally mean you must be able to see a point "in the air", or could this work beneath the waves?

Comment: Voting to reopen- this question is specifically about a spell requiring something needing to appear *in the air*, not about the general behavior of lightning underwater.

Comment: Are you asking if you can create a storm above the sea/lake/river while being underwater? Or are you asking if you can create an underwater storm while being underwater?

Comment: I was asking about both situations, really, but mainly wanted to know if it could be done while completely underwater, including the origin point of the spell. Yes, the wording as written does say "in the air" but I don't think they were thinking about circumstances like an underwater battle when they wrote the spell description.

Comment: Sorry, not really, because just prior to your 'sticking point' it also says "if you can't see a point in the air", which seems to indicate the problem isn't so much what it can "accommodate" --which would be the problem in a low room--as it is "If you can't see a point", which you *could* underwater. Therefore your answer is subjective and not particularly based on any fact.

Answer (score 13):

#### I would rule that submarine areas could not accommodate a storm cloud.

The sticking point for me is in the example they give:

> for example, if you are in a room that can't accommodate the cloud

It seems to me that this spell description really wants this storm cloud to form in normal storm cloud areas, such as while out of doors. Just as a small indoor space could not accommodate a proper storm cloud, I would rule that underwater areas could not either.

Answer (score 8):

> Does this literally mean you must be able to see a point "in the air"

**Yes**, it does. I'm sorry my answer is that short, but it's that simple.